# Can't assign array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to create an array of signal ( so an array of array), based on 2 cell array : Piste and Data. The program signal() get the number of the signal it has to fetch and which columns it has to sum, and it works by itself.

But when i launch :

```
Piste = mainapp.Piste;
[s,~]=size(Data);
app.x=[];
app.y=[];
app.name=[];
app.time=[];
for i=1:s
    [app.x(i),app.y(i),app.name,app.time]=signal(Data{i},Piste);
end
```

i get `Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the right side.`
I think the problem is with app.x(i) and app.y(i), but i don't know how to fix it (name and time are always the same).

Thank you for your help

Comment: please run the following line and see what chunk size you are trying to assign: size(signal(Data{i},Piste))

Comment: `p=signal(4,{'1'});
size(p)
ans =

           1      128059
`

Comment: However signal read a text file which contains the data, so for different input the size might change

Comment: So you may want to use cell array, something like app.y = {}; and then use {} when assigning into y